# Change default mount point for udisks

Tags: mount, udev, plasma5, udisks

KDE Plasma on Arch Linux mounts removable devices to `/run/media/[user]/*` by default, but, as I had an Ubuntu derivative before, I need it to be mounted to `/media/[user]` because of the symlinks and file paths on that removable device.

How do I change that mount point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KDE relies on udisks for mounting removable medias.

`man udisks` tells :

> UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED : If set to 1, the filesystem on the device
> will be mounted in a shared directory (e.g.  /media/VolumeName)
> instead of a private directory (e.g./run/media/$USER/VolumeName) when
> the Filesystem.Mount() method is handled.

I think this is precisely what you are looking for.

BTW I am not aware of any possibility to change VolumeName in $USER

Comment: There's an article for udisks on ArchWiki, which has a tutorial on how to change the mount point: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks#Mount_to_/media_(udisks2)